# How to convert a List<Long> to Map<Long, Long>

Tags: java, java-8

I have the below code and would like to use java 8 to convert a list of `Long` to a `Map<Long,Long>`.

```
Long globalVal= 10;
List<Long> queryLongs = Arrays.asList(600L,700L,800L);
Map<Long, Long> map = queryLongs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i, globalVal)));
```

I get an error when I try to map the individual value in the list as the key of the map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument of `toMap` is also a `Function`, so you can't just pass `globalVal`.

```
Map<Long, Long> map = queryLongs.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                                                          i->globalVal));
```

Comment: I get the issue saying that my variable globalVal shoud be final or effectivefinal. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @Erica Are you changing its value anywhere? If you are, it can't be used in a lambda expression. If you are not, it is effectively final, and everything should be fine.

Comment: @Erica, just copy it in a temporary `final` variable and use that one in the lambda

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Didier. Keeping a copy of the variable into a final one helped.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Eran

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way without using streams (still using Java 8 features, though):

```
Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
queryLongs.forEach(i -> map.put(i, globalVal));
```